# Finding probability of drawing red and blue balls from two boxes.

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, conditional-probability

Consider a game that invovles two boxes, where inside each box there is a red ball and a blue ball.

The player first draws a ball from box 1 and place it inside box 2, then the player draws a ball from box 2.

If the ball being drawn out of box 2 has a different color than the ball being put in earlier, then the player wins.

- Let event **E** be the event where a **red ball** is drawn from **box 1**.
- Let event **F** be the event where a **blue ball** is drawn from **box 2**.
- Let event **W** be the event that the player **wins the game**.

---

Task:

1. Calculate the probability of event F, P(F).
2. Find out if event E and F are independent.
3. Find out if event E and W are independent.

---

**Task 1**

This one's easy. I drew the probability tree for convenience.

P(F) = (2/6) + (1/6) = 1/2

[image]

---

**Task 2**

E and F are independent if: P(E|F) = P(E)

P(E|F) = P(E "INTERSECT" F)/P(F) = (1/4)/(1/2) = 1/2 = P(E)

So I guess they're independent? I wasn't expecting that.

---

**Task 3**

E and W are independent if: P(E|W) = P(W)

P(E|W) = P(E "INTERSECT" W)/P(W) = (1/6)/(1/3) = 1/3 = P(W)

Again, they're independent?

---

I find that hard to believe.

Surely event E (drawing a red ball from box 1) should have an affect on event F and W.

To say they're independent would mean that they don't affect each other at all. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Type `$\Pr(E \mid F) = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(F)}$` to produce $\Pr(E \mid F) = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(F)}$ or type `$$\Pr(E \mid F) = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(F)}$$` to display $$\Pr(E \mid F) = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(F)}$$ on a separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events $E$ and $F$ are independent if $\mathbb{P}(E \cap F) = \mathbb{P}(E) \cdot \mathbb{P}(F) $.

Using conditional probability, $\mathbb{P}(E \cap F) = \mathbb{P}(F |E)\cdot \mathbb{P}(E) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}.$

On the other hand,  $\mathbb{P}(E) \cdot \mathbb{P}(F) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.$ Since  $\mathbb{P}(E \cap F) \neq \mathbb{P}(E) \cdot \mathbb{P}(F)$ we conclude that the events $E$ and $F$ are dependent. The third task is similar.